# Filter Cells that matches partially

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have data in cell **C50:C59** like this

```
1.A Level Redspot P1 Topical-2Pcs
2.A Level Redspot M1 Topical-2 Pcs
3.O LEVEL BIOLOGY REVISION GUIDE (CAMBRIDGE)- 4 PCS
4.A LEVEL REDSPOT YEARLY ALL SUBJECT (2 SET)
5.O LEVEL CHEMISTRY REVISION GUIDE (CAMBRIDGE)- 2 PCS
6.O LEVEL PHYSICS REVISION GUIDE (CAMBRIDGE)- 2 PCS
7.O LEVEL CAMBRIDGE WORKBOOK 1 SET
```

For example, when I type in cell *B49*, **"a red"** I want it to filter out cells containing these text partially

```
1.A Level Redspot P1 Topical-2Pcs
2.A Level Redspot M1 Topical-2 Pcs
4.A LEVEL REDSPOT YEARLY ALL SUBJECT (2 SET)
```

tried using filter and search,
**C50:C59 contains the data**,
**B49 is my search box** but it requires exact text in cell **B49** to filter out, I want it to search and filter out if it matches any cell partially

```
=filter(C50:C59,search(B49,C50:C59))
```

Please give me some hint, it will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a simple query to for this task:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(LOWER(C50:C56), "where Col1 contains '"&B49&"'"))
```

[image: 0]

for total casing try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY(LOWER(C50:C56), 
 "where Col1 contains'"&B49&"'"), C50:C56, 1, 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: what i wish to do is search using multiple word without maintaing sequence or wrtiting the whole word

for example typing "lev red top che" will filter "a level topical chemistry redspot"